# Zend application without private folder

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

I have a Zend application hosted in a subdomain zend.example.com, my hosting provider makes a folder "zend" inside the public folder for the domain and this can not be changed, so I can access to my zend applicacion folder contents from the main domain, like example.com/application/Bootstrap.php where the "public" folder for the zend app would be called "zend" in order to comply with the hosting provider,
Is there a way (maybe with htaccess) that I can prevent access to the application folder contents? Thanks

Comment: please let me know if it's not clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do block access to application, library and any other folder that should be private with something like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(application|library)(/.*)?$ - [F]
```

Comment: should I use this in the parent folder? I mean, at the same level of "zend" folder..

Comment: you put the htaccess in you public folder (where example.com point)